# WCF RIA Services Dynamic Compression not working on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: silverlight, compression, iis-7.5, wcf-ria-services

I was hoping somebody could please help with a compression issue with WCF Ria services.

I have been developing a Silverlight 4 LOB application in Visual Studio 2010 on my development machine running Windows 7.

I successfully (and painlessly) configured dynamic compression for the binary responses of the domain services when hosting on this machine on IIS 7.5.

I repeated the exact process on the production server running Windows Server 2008 R2 - but it did not work at all.

I verified the compression in the response using Fiddler2. I also repeated the process on multiple Windows 7 and two other Windows server 2008 R2 machines with identical results. The IIS version on both machines is 7.5.7600.16385.

If you have had success in this configuration, please help. I'm sure it is a common requirement.

Here are the detailed steps that work on Windows 7:

1) Regular deploy in IIS application.

2) Enable alll roles/features for compression (dynamic and static) in IIS and enable for all directories in iss manager.

3) Edit applicationHost.config in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config : add in :

```
 <dynamicTypes>

            ...

            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />

    <add mimeType="application/msbin1" enabled="true" />

          ....

        </dynamicTypes>
```

4) Refresh application pool (configured to .net 4 Integrated)

Thanks in advance. I've been going gray over this.

Kind Regards

Lawrence